# SvcUtil and 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' cannot be converted to 'System.Xml.XmlElement' compiler error

Tags: error-handling, svcutil.exe

I always recieve the above error when I generate a proxy class for my service using `SvcUtil`. The service is exposing a property that is of `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` type. The `SvcUtil` generates a `System.Xml.XmlElement` type property unfortunately. On the other hand if I'm using Add Reference in VS to generate the proxy class, everything's ok. I tried the latest 4.0 version of `SvcUtil` from the NETFX 4.0 Tools folder, but still with no luck.

Comment: You should not be exposing a .net specific type like this in a datacontract. Why not generate a strongly typed class for the xml structure or just expose a string?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out.  I am also running into this with a service passing back a Drawing object.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking, like I was, the answer is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/42dbe820-3f59-4662-9664-83999e1746c0

Yaron Naveh suggests adding a /reference argument to SvcUtil.exe.

> svcutil /reference:"c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"  http://localhost...

Comment: Thanks, found this really quick and saved me some time :)